# What is wrong in the following c code prints garbage value?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x,int y)
{
    int add;
    add=x+y;
    printf("\nadd=%d",add);
    return add;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=1;b=2;
    sum(a,b);
    printf("\nsum=%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 
>   add=3
>   sum=4195760

Whats is wrong here, why the return of the addition is printing a garbage value in the main function.

Comment: 1) please dont tag unrelated languages 2) you never use the return value and then you print the value of a function pointer

Comment: 3) Turn your complier’s warnings to the max

Comment: I got it from this (2)you never use the return value and then you print the value of a function pointer.............. Unaware of coding from my and Thanks for you time

Comment: Remove `sum(a,b);`, change `printf("\nsum=%d",sum);` to `printf("\nsum=%d",sum(a,b));`. And finally start reading your C text book.

Comment: @user463035818 It is at least controversial—if not outright bad—to suggest that local variables should be initialized immediately when declared.Initializing them to a dummy value because the intended value is not available yet at the declaration makes bug harder to identify with static and dynamic analyzers, in exchange for making the program deterministic (but still buggy).

Comment: @Olaf I dont think this is going anywhere. I will just delete my comments

Comment: It's a _declaration_ and a _definition_. With an _initialiser_. "Initialisation" is a process. The term is a bit ambivalent, as setting an object in any way (could be by reading file input) is also called "initialisation" in common language.

Answer (score 5):

```
sum(a,b);
```

This is the problem You are printing the value of function (The pointer poiting to the function ,garbage value) rather than a variable which has the value of the sum ! You should use `int ans=sum(a,b);printf("%d",ans);` which will give you the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

You have a function named `sum` but you aren't calling it in the `printf()`. What you're doing is using it's address.

By writing

```
int sum(int x,int y)
{
    int add;
    add=x+y;
    printf("\nadd=%d",add);
    return add;
}
```

You have declared and implemented a function named `sum` who receives 2 `int`s, and outputs 1. However, each time you use this `sum` without the `()` (like in your `printf`) you just tell the compiler to fetch you the value of that symbol, and the value of a function symbol, is its address, hence the weird value you got.

Fix by:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=1;b=2;
    int s = sum(a,b);  /* Option 1 - save output of sum into a variable s */
    printf("\nsum=%d",s); /* use that variable */

    /* Option 2 */
    /* skip the line sum(a,b); and call the function from inside printf */

    printf("\nsum=%d",sum(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("\nsum=%d",sum);
```

This line is trying to print out `sum` however sum is not declared as a `int` but as a function. Therefore it's printing the pointer to the function `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

in printf you are trying to print value of sum, which is function name. name of the function holds address. so it is printing address of the function sum.
To print the actual result you have to call the function sum(a,b)

```
 printf("\nsum=%d",sum(a,b));
```